# JQueryTools live?

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

I´m using JQuery Tools http://flowplayer.org/tools/ in one big project.

The issues is: When I load a page using ajax all this JQuery Tools stuff stop working. I know I have to re-bind the events or use jQuery.Live but I don´t know how to do this with JQuery Tools.

I need methods like

```
$(".element").overlay(...)
$(".element").tabs(...)
```

workin live after using jQuery.load()  (Ajax)

Anybody know how to do this please?

Here the update with the ajax and live code:

```
$(".commentlist h3 a").click( function () {
  $('#container').html('loading').load('test.php #business-wrapper', function() {
     alert('Load was performed.');
  });
  return false;
});
```

The test.php contain this tabs and 'load' event does not work with ajax an without ajax does not work either

```
$("ul.tabs").live('load', function() {
  $(this).tabs("div.panes > div", { effect: 'fade', current: 'active', tabs: 'li' }); 
})
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have the load event for this:

```
$.live('load', function(event) {
  $(this).overlay();
});
```

Comment: I try this but only work witj .live('click') and only after click the first time. So I have to click the first tie before works.

load or ready does not work. ¿How can be possible this?

Comment: $.live('load') does not work but $.live('click') yes. I can I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are replacing your elements, then you need to re-run that code on them in your ajax success or complete function.  Here's an example making it into a function (you could duplicate it, this is to keep it tidy/easy to maintain):

```
function setupStuff(context) {
  $(".element", context).overlay(...)
  $(".element", context).tabs(...)
}

$.ajax({
   //Stuff...
   success: function(data) {
     //Stuff with results...
     setupStuff(data);
   }
});
```

In `document.ready` call it initially:

```
$(function() {
  setupStuff(document);
});
```

Comment: It´s does not work neither :( . I think is a JQuery Tool stuff

Comment: @deryck - Try changing your `.load()` callback function to this:
`function (context) { $("ul.tabs", context).tabs("div.panes > div", { effect: 'fade', current: 'active', tabs: 'li' }); }`